# Append/merge tables with different structure into one table in Hive?

Tags: python, hive

I have couple of input tables as shown in the picture. I want to create an Output table that includes columns from both the input tables as shown in the picture. No of columns and column names in the input tables can change at anypoint. I want to create a dynamic process that reads the input tables and create output table with all the columns. I am using python. Has anyone done this before? Any help is much appreciated.

[image: Input and Output Table]

Comment: what should you do when id's in both tables match?

Comment: What format is your input data in? A CSV file?

Comment: Input data is in hive table.

Comment: @VamsiPrabhala Nothing just merge the data into one table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution that can achieve what you want. However, since I do not know your data format, I can only make up how they will arrive.
If you are using Hive and downloaded your data as csv or excel, you can simply replace the code below with `df1 = pd.read_excel(filepath)` or `df1 = pd.read_csv(filepath)`

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
        'Col1': [1,11,22],
        'Col2': ['qwe','ert','eryy'],
        'Col3': ['111','222','333'],
        'Col4': ['match1','fail1','fail2'],
        'Col5': ['fail3','fail4','match2'],
        })
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
        'Col1': [123, 433],
        'Col4': ['match1','fail12'],
        'Col5': ['fail33','match2'],
        'Col6': ['fee','foo'],
        'Col7': ['spam','spam'],
        })

df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='outer', 
               left_on=['Col1','Col4','Col5'], 
               right_on=['Col1','Col4','Col5'])

print (df3)
#   Col1  Col2 Col3    Col4    Col5 Col6  Col7
#0     1   qwe  111  match1   fail3  NaN   NaN
#1    11   ert  222   fail1   fail4  NaN   NaN
#2    22  eryy  333   fail2  match2  NaN   NaN
#3   123   NaN  NaN  match1  fail33  fee  spam
#4   433   NaN  NaN  fail12  match2  foo  spam
```

Comment: @Bob, has this helped you solve your problem? Please let me know. Thanks

Comment: @Bob Good to hear. If this answer helped you solve your issue, please help mark it as the correct answer. Thanks